# Как распарсить строку времени с помощью QDateTime::fromString()?

Tags: qt, c++

Есть строки, содержащие время, например, "Tue Jun 22 16:40:19 +0000 2010".
"+0000" присутствует во всех строках. Хочется перевести все это в `QDateTime` с помощью

```
QDateTime::fromString ( const QString & string, const QString & format )
```

Помогите составить шаблон для таких строк. Конечно, есть мануал Qt, но там все это как-то мутно объясняется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, распарсить с помощью одной этой команды не получится. Надо разбить строку на 3 поля -- извлечь UTC смещение +ХХХХ и отдельно его обработать. Это можно сделать с помощью функций QString либо применить более тяжелую артилерию в виде регекспов.

Comment: И добавлю: не забыть про QLocale, а то QDateTime будет ожидать в строке `Вс. апр. 22` вместо `Sun Apr 22`.